# Penalty for trespassing on a gas station parking lot in Kentucky

Tags: kentucky, trespassing

My brother was parked at a gas station before they opened at 4:45 am to rest his eyes.  At 5:00 am when they opened, he went inside, used the restroom, and did not buy anything.  Owner asked him to leave and that it was not a rest area.  Owner of gas station called the cops, cops showed up gave him a chance to leave, but he told them he was tired and didn't feel safe to drive yet.  They arrested him for criminal trespassing.  What type of punishment could he face?

Comment: Has he asked his lawyer?

Comment: If not, has his parent/guardian/carer asked his lawyer?

Answer (score 3):

This violation of [KRS 511.080](https://apps.legislature.ky.gov/law/statutes/statute.aspx?id=52944), criminal trespass in the third degree, is a "violation", which results in a [fine](https://apps.legislature.ky.gov/law/statutes/statute.aspx?id=20098) not more than $250. The fine shall not be imposed if he is indigent pursuant to [KRS Chapter 31](https://apps.legislature.ky.gov/law/statutes/chapter.aspx?id=37178).

Answer (score 2):

Criminal Trespass in Kentucky [has three degrees:](https://apps.legislature.ky.gov/law/statutes/chapter.aspx?id=39377)

> 511.060 Criminal trespass in the first degree.
>
> (1) A person is guilty of criminal trespass in the first degree when he or she knowingly
> enters or remains unlawfully in a dwelling.
>
> (2) Criminal trespass in the first degree is a Class A misdemeanor [...]

> 511.070 Criminal trespass in the second degree.
>
> (1) A person is guilty of criminal trespass in the second degree when he or she
> knowingly enters or remains unlawfully in a building or upon premises as to which
> notice against trespass is given by fencing or other enclosure
>
> (2) Criminal trespass in the second degree is a Class B misdemeanor, [...]

> 511.080 Criminal trespass in the third degree
>
> (1) A person is guilty of criminal trespass in the third degree when he knowingly enters
> or remains unlawfully in or upon premises.
>
> (2) Criminal trespass in the third degree is a violation [...]

Parking and not leaving after being told to does not trespass on a dwelling or building, so it is only fitting the third degree possible. As such the prescribed punishment is a *violation*, [which comes out to a fine of at maximum 250 USD.](https://apps.legislature.ky.gov/law/statutes/statute.aspx?id=20098)

> 534.040 Fines for misdemeanors and violations.
>
> (2) Except as otherwise provided for an offense defined outside this code, a person who
> has been convicted of any offense other than a felony shall be sentenced, [...] , to pay a fine in an amount not to
> exceed:
>
> (a) For a Class A misdemeanor, five hundred dollars ($500); or
>
> (b) For a Class B misdemeanor, two hundred fifty dollars ($250); or
>
> (c) For a violation, two hundred fifty dollars ($250).